# Qt Custom ProgressBar can't refresh (paintEvent)

Tags: qt, progress-bar, refresh, paintevent

i've created a custom progress bar, but when i call the ***SetValue()*** method the ***paintEvent*** method (overrided) is not called, so the progress bar show just the veryfirst value.

This is the Header **grafica_progressbar.h**

```
    #ifndef GRAFICA_PROGRESSBAR_H
    #define GRAFICA_PROGRESSBAR_H

    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QProgressBar>
    #include <QPaintEvent>

    #include <QPainter>
    #include <QBrush>
    #include <QStyle>
    #include <QPen>
    #include <QColor>

    class grafica_ProgressBar : public QProgressBar
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        grafica_ProgressBar();

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    };

    #endif // GRAFICA_PROGRESSBAR_H
```

and this is the cpp **grafica_progressbar.cpp**

```
#include "grafica_progressbar.h"

grafica_ProgressBar::grafica_ProgressBar()
{

}

void grafica_ProgressBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    int tmpValue = value();
    int TopPos = QStyle::sliderPositionFromValue(minimum(), maximum(), tmpValue, width());

    QPainter p(this);

    if (tmpValue<maximum()*0.85)
    {
        p.setPen(Qt::green);
        p.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green));
    }
    else
    {
        p.setPen(QColor(255,51,51));
        p.setBrush(QColor(255,51,51));
    }

     p.drawRect(0,0,TopPos,height());


    p.setPen(Qt::gray);
    p.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::lightGray));
    p.drawRect(TopPos, 0, width(), height()); //riempio tutto il resto di grigio


    p.setPen(Qt::black);
    p.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
    p.drawText(0,0, width(), height(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(tmpValue ) + " bar");
}
```

and this is the first call into the userinterface costructor

```
TestProgres = new grafica_ProgressBar();

ui->gridLayout->addWidget(TestProgres);

TestProgres->setMaximum(400);
TestProgres->setValue(300);
```

if i try to call **TestProgres->setValue(200)** inside  a button, i can't see any refresh.

So, where's the problem?

Comment: Try to call [`update`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) after `setValue`.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works without manual update. Just added an action to `MainWindow` adding 10 to ProgressBar value each time. Show your code where you call `setValue`.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the method that is associated with the button? I also confirm that your code works since setValue() of QProgressBar calls update() internally so there is no need to call update() returned.

Comment: Same here. Your code works. Failure is somewhere else.

Comment: Now it works!

Clean Project, rebuild  (like last 10 times) and pray.   :|

Thanks to all

Comment: Do not edit your title to `[SOLVED]` or similar. Instead, answer your own question, and provide us with the solution, as well as mark it as accepted. This will help future readers on the site.

Answer (score 1):

The code starts to work after a "**clean, rebuilt & run**" operation.

I've edited the code just for showing the correct value.

Thanks to all!